# Running python code through user friendly interface

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

**additional question**
I'm working on a project for a family member, I have fairly limited experience with Python. I have written my script on Python, and it works exactly how I need. The code takes a photo and adds a red border to either the length or the width to create a square.

My issue is my family member does not use Python, and after some light research I have come across tkinter for a GUI. I would like to have a text box where the image name can be typed, and that runs the code from the input line.

I have it where you type MyImage.PNG into the console and it saves the border version into the same file. Also, I understand how to design with tkinter--just not how to actually execute my script with the textbox/buttons. Any advice on how to achieve this?

**I would like to call images from a file, without having to individually type the image name. Is that possible through an open loop possibly? Or even using a Tkinter widget to read the images file, create a list from the file, and then individually be able to select each image and hit enter.**

Thank you!

```
from PIL import Image, ImageOps
import math
original = input("Please enter an input: ")
im = Image.open(original)

print(im.size)
print(type(im.size))

w, h = im.size
print('width: ', w)
print('height:', h)

if w>h:
    x = w - h
    b = math.floor(x/2)
    a = 0
if w<h:
    x = h - w
    a = math.floor(x/2)
    b = 0
        
    
def add_border(input_image, output_image, border, color=0):
    img = Image.open(input_image)
    if isinstance(border, int) or isinstance(border, tuple):
        bimg = ImageOps.expand(img, border=border, fill=color)
    else:
        raise RuntimeError('Border is not an integer or tuple!')
    bimg.save(output_image)
if __name__ == '__main__':
     add_border(original,
                output_image= 'border' + original,
                border=(a,b,a,b),
                color='indianred')
```

Comment: You could use `filedialog.askopenfilename()` in `tkinter`, create a button to call your function

Comment: What operating system is this running on, please?

Comment: I am running this on windows

Comment: @jizhihaoSAMA I have used that, and it works. I am still a step off, I need to get the selected photo (which I currently have coming up as a label) from the file dialog into my input command. Any advice? Sorry if that is not clear, I'm still trying to understand everything as I work through it!

Comment: Rather than write a GUI, you may find it easier to put a script on the user's Desktop then they can use the familiar Windows File Explorer thing to select a file and just drop it onto your script... https://stackoverflow.com/q/44577446/2836621

Comment: `askopenfilename()` will return the path.After that, you could use `entry.insert()` to put the path in your `entry`.

Answer (score 1):

Tkinter has an input field function so you could do something like:

```
from tkinter import *

def Get_Name_Of_Picture():
    original=str(PicName.get())

PicName=Entry(screen)
PicName.pack()

Button(screen, text='Enter', command=Get_Name_Of_Picture).pack(side=LEFT)
```

Something like that(you might have to put the rest of the code in the Get_Name_Of_Picture function) but this will allow the user to type an input into an entry field, and once they are done hit the enter button which will get the string of what was typed and so on.

If you need more advice just comment on this answer and I will try to help.

Comment: Thank you! That allows me to enter the image name and save it in the same file. I'm not entirely sure how or why it's working, but I messed with it until it did (I had to tweak it).

Comment: Also, I will work on it tomorrow more for design and ease of use--so I might be back!

Comment: Sounds good! If you want a full (I am lazy so full means like 2-3 sentences) explanation just ask

Comment: Hello, I've added another question to my part. Can you take a look? thanks!

Comment: I sometimes struggle with image stuff but give that other comment from @jizhihaosama a try